# Convert ER-Win model to Aqua Data Studio

Tags: entity-relationship, erwin, aquafold

I am looking at converting some existing CA ER-Win data models (.erwin [9.x file]) over to Aqua Data Studio.

Is there any direct way of doing this?

One can of course do a forward engineer into a DB and the reverse engineer. However, that kind of defeats the purpose given logical and physical model representations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Aqua Data Studio, it is possible to export an ER Model in ERX Format (with file extension .erx) for use in ERWin - you would need to navigate to Tools -> Export to ERX Format.
However, there is no direct import feature. Aqua Data Studio's ER Modeler only supports physical models.

Comment: Thanks. Just confirmed my suspicion. A bit of a pity though.